# How to boost the process of checking two strings have the same characters in C?

Tags: c

for example
string1='abbbc'
string2='agdee'
they have the same character 'a'
so i have to return 1;

else if  like
string1'abbb'
string2'cccd'
they don't have any same character
so i have to return 0;

how to boost this searching process?
how to do this rather than using double for loop in C?

Comment: Unless the strings are very long, don't worry about the efficiency. Just do it the simple way.

Comment: Well, here's a hint: instead of a double for loop, use two for loops.

Comment: are the two strings always same length and are you checking for the same characters at the same position?

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative algorithm:

- Have an array of bool, size big enough to hold the highest character (e.g. ascii z is 122) you will have
- Loop over the first string converting each char to its numerical and set the bool in that array index to true
- Loop over the second string changing each char to numeric and using it to read the bool in that array position
- If you encounter a true, return 1
- if you reach the end of the array with no trues encountered return 0

This essentially converts the "wase cpu time" of checking every char against every other char (two strings of length 5, 25 comparisons) into a "burn some memory" one (two strings of length 5, up to 10 comparisons, at the expense of holding maybe 122 bools worth of memory), so there's a trade off point that varies with the length of the strings and the size of the charset.. eg two strings of length 5 that could be any Unicode.. it ain't worth burning 65k bools of memory just to save 15 ish comparisons

Comment: That's the way to do it... Just like to add: 1) The array should be able to hold any char-valur (typically 256) and 2) remember to convert to unsigned char before indexing the array

Comment: if all characters are 'a'~'z' can you boost this method?

Comment: @AtWell if all characters are 'a'~'z', can YOU boost this method?

Comment: @AtWell you didn't post any code, so neither did I.. I figured it's homework that you'll get more out of by doing it yourself 